# Xcode how to find text in string constants in project?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to find a string in the project, but it searches everywhere. What I want is to search only in string constants? 
I mean, if we have
auto hello = "hello"
it should find only the second "hello" and ignore the first.
Is it possible in Xcode? I have Xcode 6.4

Comment: Why don't you make a text search for "hello" (quotes included)?

Comment: Because hello may be a part of a string, for example "hello Kerem" and "hello" won't find this line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to search including your "" ? ex: [CTRL+F "hello"]

Comment: But what if I have a string "Karim, hello, how are you?" then I need to find the "hello" there?